# Saving a List of Lists in Java?

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I am creating a bukkit plugin that requires more of a customization level than most plugins. My configuration files will be in this format:

```
zones:
  zone:
    string: string
  zone:
    string: string2
```

I need to be able to get each value in each list. For instance; i have (X) number of zones based upon how many lists are in the `zones:` list.

I know i can get the value of a list like this: `this.getConfig().getString("zones.zone.string");`

But in this case, i have two `zone` lists.

I have tried using this method, but could not get it to work (JUST an Explanation)

```
foreach(zone in zones) {
    // Get each value in the list
}
```

How would i get all the zones in the zones list?

**EDIT**
I am needing to iterate through each zone and get its inner values. But i am not sure how to do it with Bukkit's API.

Comment: Try posting your question using a *real* example. You probably need to parse `string` by splitting it using a regex or something alike.

Comment: What exactly is the issue? Are you trying to figure out the correct syntax for the for-each loop?

Comment: @alfasin I forgot to mention this is a bukkit plugin. I am using bukkit's way to get the information from the config. Would i have to parse the file?

Comment: @ZongZhengLi Yes, and how would i get it so i can iterate through each zone in the zones list of the config.yml file.

Comment: @ZongZhengLi No, not the format on how to do it. But how would i get it form the config.yml file. Can i use bukkit's getList function to get each list in that list?

Comment: Whoever downvoted, could you please explain why so i can improve my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more research into it, i found that i could use this to iterate through all the values in each "zone"

```
for(String zone : Plugin.zones.getKeys(false)) {
    System.out.println(Plugin.getConfig().getInt("zones."+zone));
}
```

Please feel free to post a better answer and i will look it over. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
this.getConfig().getConfigurationSection("zones").getValues(false)
```

I don't have many experience with Bukkit, but you can try this. It should get a list of paths to every zone. Then you only go through it with foreach loop and get every value of the string you need.

Comment: A list of paths for the zones? The path for every single zone would be `zones.zone` correct? I am needing to loop through each zone and get the values from it.

Comment: I can see, you have a few sections called "zone" in your section called "zones". If you need to get values of strings in your zones, then you need to know path to every "zone" section. Your "zones.zone.string" is an absolute path to the first element.

And again - I don't really know if it is the solution, that works or you need

Comment: Alright, that makes sense. But how would i iterate through each zone? That is what i am trying to explain, but people keep downvoting it because they don't understand what i am trying to convey.

Comment: The method getValues, gets a list (something like "ConfigurationSectionList"). You can use this code to iterate through the list:

    foreach(ConfigurationSection item in ConfigurationSectionList      variableName){
    this.getConfig().getString(item.GetValue("string"));
    }